# Csv file with different number of data in each row

Tags: java, arrays, csv

basically I'm trying to store data from a text file and perform some tasks with that data. So far I've parsed the data into different types (component, stock num, stock, and price), loaded the data into an object and put the object into an array list. I have a problem though as some of the rows in the txt file only have four data types while everything else has 5.

Therefore, I can only parse it to four data types instead of 5 because I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception` because diode doesn't have anything at index[4]. I know that I should use the length of the array but I'm not sure how.  Also, how would I add together everything in a data type such as stock and get the total stock for all the components? Thanks.

```
    try
    {
        List<Inventory> invItem = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.txt"));


        String fileRead = br.readLine();

        while (fileRead != null)
        {
            String[] tokenize = fileRead.split(",");
            String tempItem = tokenize[0];
            String tempNumber = tokenize[1];
            double tempStock = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[2]);
            double tempPrice = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[3]);
            double tempResist = Double.parseDouble(tokenize[4]);
            Inventory tempObj = new Inventory(tempItem, tempNumber, tempPrice, tempStock, tempResist);
            invItem.add(tempObj);
            fileRead = br.readLine();



        }
```

Comment: I think, this is very first problem you may be seeing with data, but potentially there may be more. Try using existing library and it has solved all those issues like `apache commons`, `apache-poi` etc. see example https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-csvs-in-java-with-apache-commons-csv/

Comment: I would say its not valid csv format, the most easy way will be, if possible, then just simply add empty values in particular cases, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only using some pseudo code here, because you haven't showed us what you have tried so far, to try to explain what you need to do:

```
for each line in CSV-file {
  split line by ',' and store in array
  check first item in array =>
    if array[0].equals("diode") => create diode object from array of size 4
    if array[0].equals("capacitor") => create capacitor object from array of size 5
    ...
  store created object in a List<>
}
```

Both the diode class and the capacitor class extends a class that is used for the type of `List<>`

---

Now that your question has been updated with some code, I will give an example with real code. This example uses only an `Inventory` class, no `Diode` or `Capacitor` classes.

```
public class Inventory {
    private String item;
    private String number;
    private double price;
    private double stock;
    private double resist;

    public Inventory(String[] csvLine) {
        if (csvLine.length > 0) item = csvLine[0];
        if (csvLine.length > 1) number = csvLine[1];
        if (csvLine.length > 2) stock = Double.parseDouble(csvLine[2]);
        if (csvLine.length > 3) price = Double.parseDouble(csvLine[3]);
        if (csvLine.length > 4) resist = Double.parseDouble(csvLine[4]);
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

And some code using this class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Inventory> invItem = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.txt"));

    String fileRead;

    while ((fileRead = br.readLine()) != null) {
        invItem.add(new Inventory(fileRead.split(",")));
    }

    br.close();

    double totalStock = 0;
    for (Inventory inv : invItem) {
        totalStock += inv.getStock();
    }
    System.out.println(totalStock); // prints the total stock
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is... to check the length before attempting to read values. This code can help:

```
 double tempResist = tokenize.length <= 4 ? 0 : 
        Double.parseDouble(tokenize[4]);
```

However, it is even better to ensure that all resistors have length 5; otherwise you would receive no warning when invalid resistors (missing a resistance value) are read:

```
 double tempResist = "resistor".equals(tempItem) ? 0 : 
        Double.parseDouble(tokenize[4]);
```

And, even better, you would have separate `Resistor` and `Capacitor` subclasses of `Item`, and have an `ItemParser` class with a `static Item parse(String[] tokens)` method that parses the common bits, and creates an object of the correct subclass, passing the remaining tokens to its constructor. In their constructors, resistors would complain if they are missing values, while capacitors would complain if they get passed excess, unexpected values. This would also complain if a "chicken" is read, because there would be no subclass to parse its values.

Edit: it is better to have an `ItemParser` as a separate class than to place that functionality in the `Item` class directly, because this allows you to add new types if `Item` without touching the base `Item` base class.